# Inductively Defining Sets of Strings

Tags: string, set, logic, discrete-mathematics, induction

CS student slogging through a logic class. This question has me befuddled

Inductively Defining Sets of Strings

Find an inductive definition for the following set of strings:

S = {apbcr | p is a natural number, and r is a natural number greater than 0} ****the p and r are superscripts****

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest the following definition:

[image: bc \in S\a^pbc^r \in S \implies {a^{p+1}bc^r,a^pbc^{r+1},a^{p+1}bc^{r+1}} \subset S]